# Django Form CreateView for model within model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have the following models:-

```
class Address(models.Models):
   line_1 = ...
   country = ...

class User(models.Models):
   name = ...
   mailing_address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
   billing_address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
```

I want to create a form view that will allow the user to enter his/her details and then insert his/her mailing and billing address.

I am using the CreateView right now but I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: Have a look at Django's [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [django-autocomplete-light](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light) package. It allows the user to 'add another' item when e.g. using a `ForeignKey`.

As a result, you will not need to populate the `Address` database upfront, but you can let users do this via the same page used by the `User` form.